# Restrict Elastic Beanstalk from creating a security group and use provided one instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

When I create a beanstalk environment using a saved configuration, it works fine but creates a new security group for no reason and attaches it to the instances. I already provide a security group to allow SSH access to the instances from VPC sources.

I followed this [thread](https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/44) and tried to restrict this behaviour with the following config inside `.ebextentions`:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBSecurityGroup: { "CmpFn::Remove" : {} }
  AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
    Properties:
      SecurityGroups:
        - sg-07f419c62e8c4d4ab
```

Now the creation process gets stuck at:

```
Creating application version archive "app-210517_181530".
Uploading stage/app-210517_181530.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: restrict-sg-poc
  Application name: stage
  Region: ap-south-1
  Deployed Version: app-210517_181530
  Environment ID: e-pcpmj9mdjb
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.1.8
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2021-05-17 12:45:35.701000+00:00
Printing Status:
2021-05-17 12:45:34    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2021-05-17 12:45:35    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-############ as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
```

How can I do this properly so that my SG is added to the instances and no new SGs are created.

PS: I am using a shared ALB so SG created for load balancers is not a problem right now.

Comment: That feature request you linked isn't implemented yet. The request is still open. So it appears what you are trying to do is not possible yet.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB but I think it works for `jbm00n` (https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/44#issuecomment-621020073) and I'm also not using SSHKeys. I realise it is just a workaround for now and the actual feature is not enabled yet.

Comment: can you plz share how did you do it? I'm having the same issue I checked the thread and I'm still at a bind @Tanmay